# Magento2.3.1 Redirecting to Cart Page after payment is successful

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

I have issue with payment , When i make payment with razorpay gateway and after successful payment it is redirecting back to cart page instead of thank you page.

Can anyone found solution for this. I referred few stackoverflow questions and tried

```
Magento\Checkout\Controller\Onepage
```

Commented out the following line

```
$session->clearQuote();
```

After that as well i am unable to place order with razorpay

Comment: Have your website use redis session?

Comment: No.. I just enabled magento2 default cache

Comment: Sorry. I mean redis session

Comment: No i am not using